Given a viably physical (isolated), quantum many body Hamiltonian, does an initial state of a superposition of energy eigenstates ever thermalize?
Given a viably physical, quantum many body Hamiltonian of a isolated system, if initially a state is prepared which is a superposition of energy eigenstates in an interval centered at E and E', not at the edges of the spectrum, does such a state ever thermalize in any sense, given a strictly unitary evolution occurs?
Thanks!

You might want to revisit what "unitary evolution" means
